# Recovering elements of a Javascript Path2D

Tags: javascript, svg, html5-canvas, path-2d

I want to examine the individual path segments of a Path2D object. For example, suppose that

```
path = new Path2D();
path.ellipse(70,90,2,2,0,0,2*Math.PI);
```

I want to pass `path` to some other function and pull out the elements of the `Path2D` so that they can be translated into another format. The big picture goal is to allow the user to create a path and translate it to TikZ for inclusion in a LaTeX document.

Is there something like Java's `Shape.getPathIterator()`, which allows one to examine each segment along a path. Can this be done Javascript? As a template, here is an outline of the Java code that does what I'm hoping to do in Javascript.

```
PathIterator p = path.getPathIterator(new AffineTransform());
while (p.isDone() == false)
  {
    double c = new double[6];
    int t = p.currentSegment(c);
    if (t == PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO)
      // (c[0],c[1]) is the "move-to" point.
    else if (t == PathIterator.SEG_LINETO)
      // (c[0],c[1]) is the "line-to" point.
    else if (t == == PathIterator.SEG_CUBICTO)
      // c[0] through c[5] specify the cubic curve
    else
      // etc., etc.
  }
```

**Editing this after seeing @Kaiido's answer.**
What I ended up doing was extending `Path2D` to a new class that is functionally identical, except that it stores each call to `arc()`, `lineTo()`, etc. to an array as the call is made. This allows me to examine the record of past calls. It may not be a sufficiently general solution for everyone, but it works for my needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there is currently nothing in the API that allows us to do that.
There are [some discussions](https://github.com/fserb/canvas2D/#parked--future-ideas) to extend the Path2D API so it's less "opaque", but nothing tangible yet, I don't think anyone is actively working on it, and we can't be sure what it will include.
The current proposal reads

> **Path2D Inspection.** Allow inspection of Path2D objects, that are currently opaque.

For what it's worth, I myself started working on this idea a few months ago, in the hope I could help this discussion get started somehow with a possible feature design.
My very ambitious idea is to bring an API like SVG's [`SVGPathData`](https://svgwg.org/specs/paths/#InterfaceSVGPathData) and add methods to Path2D like `getBBox`, `getPathData()`, `setPathData()`, `toSVGString()`, `getTotalLength()`, or `getPointAtLength()`.

You can check [this repository](https://github.com/Kaiido/path2D-inspection/) where lives my project, and below is a demo using your input.

```js
const path = new Path2D();
path.ellipse(70,90,50,20,0,0,2*Math.PI);

const svgString = path.toSVGString();
document.querySelector("pre").textContent += svgString;
document.querySelector("path").setAttribute("d", svgString);
document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d").fill(path);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Kaiido/path2D-inspection@master/build/path2D-inspection.min.js"></script>
<pre>
const path = new Path2D();
path.ellipse(70,90,50,20,0,0,2*Math.PI);
path.toSVGString();

</pre>
SVG:<br>
<svg><path fill="green"></path></svg><br>
Canvas:<br>
<canvas></canvas>
```